# Difference between ZeroMQ asynchronous http requests and Messages?

Tags: asynchronous, python-requests, zeromq, conceptual, grequests

How is using asynchronous HTTP Requests different from using Messages when it comes to sending data in ZeroMQ?

Answer (score 1):

A http request is simply the use of the hypertext transport protocol used over IP between two machines, client and server. It can be used for moving data in either direction. There's no particular restrictions as to what that data can be. An asynchronous request is simply one where the requester isn't bothering to wait for the reply having made the request; it'll use some mechanism to later rendezvous with the request, whenever that happens to come in.

Sending a message through ZeroMQ can be somewhat similar, specifically the REQ/REP pattern (request, reply). Similar to a http request, the requester will send some sort of message and the replier will reply in some way, and strictly in this pattern.

ZeroMQ uses its own protocol, zmtp, to move messages around. Again, there's nothing really limiting what data is in a message. ZeroMQ is inherently asynchronous - it's implementing the Actor programming model (though I notice that the way some implementations in some languages have eroded ZeroMQ's simplicity w.r.t. that, fitting into the language's own way of being asynchronous rather than use a poll funcion provided by ZeroMQ).

However, ZeroMQ builds many more data distribution patterns than req/rep on top of zmtp, like pub/sub, dealer/router, that http simply has no equivalent of. Further differences are that ZeroMQ can use IP, interprocess comms, or in-memory transports; this makes it highly suited for both in-application use, and for inter-machine distributed applications. I guess that a webserver could be contacted over ipc too, but I've never heard of anyone bothering to do that. Http is expected to be used over specific ports (e.g. port 80), whereas ZMQ gets used on whatever ports the developer wants (obeying the normal port allocation rules if they want a quiet life).